# Recovering Eclipse source files from .metadata folder

Tags: c++, eclipse, metadata, data-recovery, file-recovery

I'm trying to recover some .cpp source files from Eclipse projects I made over a year ago. At the time I was using Ubuntu and I would just save all my projects to the same workspace folder.

When I went to reformat my computer a long time ago I copied my workspace folder to an external hard drive. So, recently I went to look through my old projects for a source file I need and the only thing inside my workspace folder is a hidden ".metadata" folder.

Looking though that there's a .lock file, .log file and a .plugins folder. Inside the .plugins folder is two more folders, org.eclipse.cdt.core and org.eclipse.cdt.make.core. I can see my projects inside those folders but they have .pdom and .sc extensions and I'm not sure what that is.

Can anyone give me some advice as to wether or not its possible to recover the source files (.cpp files) from the data I have? I'm now using Mac OSX but I installed Ubuntu on a VM and downloaded eclipse but had no success recovering anything. Any would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your source files must have been outside the workspace folder after all. In such cases, all the workspace folder would have is metadata to organize them as a project.

If the sources were inside the workspace, you wouldnt have needed to go through the `.metadata` folder.